# Text replace using array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

I guys,
I would like replace a text adding specific links on specific words.
So, I created a dynamic array like this:

```
$replace = array  (
    "ferrari" => '<a href="x">ferrari</a>',
    "ferrari 2" => '<a href="x">ferrari 2</a>'
     etc.    
)
```

I found a way to replace the text using:

`preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $subject)`

but if in the `$subject` there is the string "ferrari 2" it will be replaced with 
[ferrari] instead of [ferrari 2].

How can I do an exact match?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Place `ferrari 2` item before `ferrari` in the array. And use `str_replace` if you are not using regular expressions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That'll get the OP some nested `a` tags which is probably not the desired result :-)

Comment: Can you post the string $subject?

Comment: Ok, then `preg_replace_callback` should be used with a pattern built from the keys. kurtafterjim, can you rearrange the items in the `$replace` array manually, or do you have no control over the array population?

Comment: somefething like : rrari\s(\d?)     '<a href="x">ferrari'. ' '$1.'</a>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the following solution:

```
$s = "he has a ferrari and ferrari 2 and what not."; // SAMPLE STRING
$replace = array  (                                  // REPLACEMENTS ARRAY
    "ferrari" => '<a href="x">ferrari</a>',
    "ferrari 2" => '<a href="x">ferrari 2</a>'
);
$keys = array_map('strlen', array_keys($replace));  // SORTING BY KEY LENGTH 
array_multisort($keys, SORT_DESC, $replace);        //   IN DESCENDING ORDER

$pat = '~' . implode("|", array_keys($replace)) . '~'; // BUILDING A PATTERN
echo $pat . "\n";  // => ~ferrari 2|ferrari~ - matches either ferrari 2 or ferrari

$res = preg_replace_callback($pat, function($m) use ($replace) { // REPLACING...
       return isset($replace[$m[0]]) ? $replace[$m[0]] : $m[0];  // IF THE KEY EXISTS,
    }, $s);                                // REPLACE WITH VALUE, ELSE KEEP THE MATCH
echo $res;  // => he has a <a href="x">ferrari</a> and <a href="x">ferrari 2</a> and what not.
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/sVy8wE)

Comment: Thanks! Your idea to order by lenght is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

change the order to:

```
$replace = array  (
   "ferrari 2" => '<a href="x">ferrari 2</a>'
   "ferrari" => '<a href="x">ferrari</a>', 
)
```

Usually when you replace, just changing the order to where the smallest keys are last solves a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the var $subject is like this:

```
$subject = 'ferrari ferrari 2';
```

Try with this:

```
$replace = array  (
    "/ferrari(?!\s+\d+)/" => '<a href="x">ferrari</a>',
    "/ferrari 2/" => '<a href="x">ferrari 2</a>'
);
echo preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $subject);
```